Is there a simple way in python to read and write a file from two separate threads?
Not familiar with the file operation and multi-threading in python, so I'm asking here. So I want to do something like this: one writing thread will write some data to a file, and another reading thread to read the data from the top of the file, but if the file is empty the reading thread would just wait until the file has content. I think it should be easy with multithreading, but experimented with some ways, didn't get it. Very much appreciate if some code snippets could be provided. Thanks!

What if your "producer" thread wrote to a Queue instead of writing to the file, and then, your "consumer" thread could write the file (assuming you even still need the file) as it reads from the Queue. Would that work for you?

The content might take too much memory if using Queue. So I'm not considering using that.

Maybe you can try WatchDog.
It's a library to monitor file system events, and you can custom your event func, like on_created, on_modified etc.
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEvent, FileSystemEventHandler

class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, path) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path
        self.record = []
    
    def on_modified(self, event: FileSystemEvent) -> None:
        super().on_modified(event)
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            self.record.append(f.read())
        print(self.record)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "file_test.txt"
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(CustomHandler(path), path)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            with open(path, "a") as f:
                f.write("Hello, world!\n")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()


I see this could work when the content needs to be read immediately after being written to the file. What if the reader wants to poll the file and read the file from where it left reading last time?
